# I made a char[] with split and am trying to make it into a String again, but I don't know why this is not working

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

Why will this code not print out a string?

```
String s = "My name is Jack";
    String[] arr = s.split("");
    char[] a = Arrays.toString(arr).toCharArray();
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(new String(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't make a `char[]` array, but rather a `String[]` array.  Use `String#toCharArray()` instead:

```
String s = "My name is Jack";
char[] letters = s.toCharArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letters));
System.out.println(new String(letters));
```

### Demo

Comment: I am trying to use split explicitly; sorry, I should have been more clear.

Comment: @jackb7890 The answer by Andy Turner seems to have you covered.  Suggesting `toCharArray` is valid IMO since it is also part of the core string API.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

It does print out a String, at least on the second println (the first println yields exactly the same output, but it does it without constructing the String).

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ojwcMq)

However, the chars of the string you are printing is obtained via:

```
char[] a = Arrays.toString(arr).toCharArray();
```

`Arrays.toString` gives you a string surrounded by `[]`, separated with commas. So `"hello"` would look like:

```
[h, e, l, l, o]
```

You then get the chars of *this* string, and try to reconstitute it into a string (which is redundant anyway, just print `Arrays.toString(arr)`).

To print the joined string, use `String.join`:

```
String.join("", arr)
```